# Ubuntu 16.04 Compile VLC for Android Failed

Tags: ubuntu, vlc

Dears,
Recently, I am confused with how to compile vlc for android successful. I try to https://wiki.videolan.org/AndroidCompile on my Ubuntu 16.04, but failed. I get the tips like:

```
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/vlc-android/vlc/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/po'
Making install in share
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/vlc-android/vlc/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/share'
  GEN      vlc.appdata.xml
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/vlc-android/vlc/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/share'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `install-exec-am'.
  GEN      vlc.appdata.xml
 /bin/mkdir -p '/home/vlc-android/vlc/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/install/share/metainfo'
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 ../../share/vlc.appdata.xml '/home/vlc-android/vlc/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/install/share/metainfo'
/usr/bin/install: cannot stat '../../share/vlc.appdata.xml': No such file or directory
make[3]: *** [install-appdataDATA] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/vlc-android/vlc/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/share'
make[2]: *** [install-am] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/vlc-android/vlc/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/share'
make[1]: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/vlc-android/vlc/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi'
make: *** [install] Error 2
vlc: make install failed
```

I had upgrade protobuf to version 3.6.1.

Comment: Share full logs. Use docker.

Comment: did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get a build by running `cp vlc/share/vlc.appdata.xml.in.in vlc/share/vlc.appdata.xml`

Have yet to test the built library

Answer (score 0):

in my case I got something like this:

```
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/vlc-android/vlc/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/share'
  GEN      vlc.appdata.xml.tmp
```

I tried to copy the original `vlc.appdata.xml` to `vlc.appdata.xml.tmp` and even to `vlc.appdata.xml.in` but the error remains....what file could be?

Thanks in advance!
Cheers